# Error CS1545 when using COM property from C#

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I have created COM interface with read/write properties:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(...),
    dual,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
IInterfaceWithProperty : IDispatch
{
     [propget, id(1)] HRESULT Property([out, retval] IInterface2** ppObject); 
     [propput, id(1)] HRESULT Property([in] IInterface* pObject); 
};
```

And when tried to use in in C#:

```
var value = object.Property;
object.Property = value;
```

got the following error:

```
error CS1545: Property, indexer, or event 'IInterfaceWithProperty .Property' is not supported 
by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 
'IInterfaceWithProperty.get_Property()' or 
'IInterfaceWithProperty.set_Property(IInterface)'
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: IInterface2 != IInterface.  While that is valid in IDL, there are not a lot of languages that support this.  I can't think of any.  Other than C#, it allows you to work around that mistake by using the get and set accessor methods directly.  Just like the error message says.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the error was that property should have the same type in getter and setter.

After changing IInterfaceWithProperty to

```
[
    object,
    uuid(...),
    dual,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
IInterfaceWithProperty : IDispatch
{
     [propget, id(1)] HRESULT Property([out, retval] IInterface2** ppObject); 
     [propput, id(1)] HRESULT Property([in] IInterface2* pObject); 
};
```

the problem disappeared.